# jQuery Cropper Stopped Working (partially)

Tags: jquery, cropper

Ive been using fengyuanchen jQuery cropper for quite a while with great results... but oddly enough, one part of it has suddenly stopped working. I have not updated the core files, nor have made any changes that could've broken it.  In fact, while searching for a solution, I found a few examples of the "avatar example" out there on the web, and ALL of them are broken in the same manner as mine.

I'm guessing its a browser / w3c standards issue, perhaps?  Not sure what else could've broken it for all of us.

The issue is, with the avatar example, when clicking the image to change, its supposed to load that image into the cropper and initialize - this isn't happening any more.

If you click the upload button, everything works fine with the newly selected image... its just that original image loading that doesn't seem to be working (nor throwing any js errors to console)

here is an example, but if you have or install the example code right out of the box, it breaks just the same.  Any help is greatly appreciated - I've racked my brain for hours on this, and got no where. :(

http://dev.phplans.com/admin/crop/examples/crop-avatar/elevation.php?plan_id=1060541&uid=3&elev_url=/media/wm/3/plans/1060541_elevation.png

thanks everyone!!
Chris

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or codepen showing the issue?

Comment: unfortunately, Im not that smart :)